# How to Covert the Selected date from the <option> and convert it to a numeric value

Tags: angular, date, controller

Given this html: 

{{period |  date: 'MMMM d, y'}}

Comment: Please try making a consistent question.

Comment: <select id="uploadperiod" ng-model="vm.uploadperiod">
 <option ng-repeat="period in vm.periods">{{period |  date: 'MMMM d, y'}}</option>
 </select>

Comment: What is your current output? How does the `period` looks like when you apply pipe?